# Mit seinem dritten Spielfilm, der Geschichte einer unglücklichen Ehe, gelingt dem Regisseur der internationale Durchbruch

Tags: sentence-structure

1. *Gelingen* is a verb that has "dative construct nominativ" so shouldn't *es* be used in this context?
2. "der Geschichte einer unglücklich Ehe" is not a relative clause because no verb there, so what kind of clause?
3. By the way, what is the meaning of "Durchbruch"?

Many Thanks

Comment: Durchbruch = breakthrough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You don't need *es* because you know what succeeded: *der internationale Durchbruch*.

You would need *es* if you were going to follow with an infinitive: *... gelingt es dem Regisseur international durchzubrechen*

2. "der Geschichte einer unglücklichen Ehe" is an attributive clause, and it's dative because Spielfilm is also dative here:

> Mit seinem dritten Spielfilm...
>   Mit der Geschichte einer unglücklichen Ehe...

3. *Durchbruch* is literally *breakthrough* . Here it means the director is breaking through into international fame

Comment: In terms of the (admittedly awkward) traditional German grammar (as tought in schools), is *der Geschichte einer unglücklichen Ehe* not simply an *Attribut* (to *Spielfilm*) by the form of *Apposition*?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann It's been a long time since I formally learned grammar, so you are probably right

Comment: Yeah, the question is, what system of descriptive grammar does Millen have in mind. I would suppose, though, that it is not some more modern linguistic form of description, rather the traditional German school grammar...